# Why is windows usb white-list based on hardware ids?

Tags: usb, group-policy, serial-number, id

On windows you can set a GPO that will allow to create a white-list of usb devices you want to allow on your computer. However, this white-list is based on the hardware ids and on the compatible ids of the device. Why is it not based on the serial number of the usb device ? To my mind it would be safer since two usb devices can have the same hardware id... Is there a way to create a white list that's based on the serial numbers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is it not based on the serial number of the USB device?

The serial number of a device isn't guaranteed to exist.  In order to connect a USB device to a USB host device, it must indicate the hardware-id (among other fields) to a USB host, otherwise, it cannot connect to that device.  There are certain fields that can be transmitted that are optional.  The serial number of the device does not have to be transmitted.

> To my mind it would be safer since two USB devices can have the same
>   hardware id...

There would nothing preventing two USB devices from having the same serial number.  A USB device tells the USB Host everything about it.  In most cases, a malicious device would be programmed in such a way, so it would be identified as a harmless device or simply as a device can be connected to the machine.

> Is there a way to create a whitelist that's based on the serial
>   numbers?

No;  You are limited to using the hardware ids and on the compatible ids.